# .NET compilation in IIS 7.5 throws an error related to web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, windows-server-2008, iis-7.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unrecognized element 'folderLevelBuildProviders'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274083/unrecognized-element-folderlevelbuildproviders)

I've setup a new EC2 Windows instance on Amazon AWS with Windows 2008 RC2. I've installed IIS 7.5 role and needed modules. I uploaded my website via ftp. Now I'm in IIS manager clicking the ".NET Complilation" button for my "Default Web Site Home" and I get an error:

```
Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\web.config
Line number: 141
Error: Unrecognized element 'folderLevelBuildProviders'
```

I've ran across several suggestions but still cannot resolve this issue. What I did was to change the application pool to to FrameWork 4 instead of 2.

I've developed my application in ASP.NET 4 framework.

Comment: Do you really need this session with the folderLevelBuildProviders ? Remove it if not needed.

Comment: Your site uses an application pool which is set to run on .NET 2.0 instead of 4.0, probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like 4.0 did not install correctly.
The web.config file you are referencing is not your applications config, but .NET it self.
Please check that 4.0 was installed correctly, or install it again.
Make sure you register .net 4.0 with IIS (you wont be able to select your APP pool if you don't)